# Typhoon - Migrating XML 1.x Implementation to 2.x

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, dependency-injection, typhoon

I have a Typhoon 1.x implementation with multiple XML files.  I have multiple apps relying on a common library.  I have a default xml file with the common library with "default" implementations for various pieces of the apps.  Then each app has its own xml file which has the ability to override the type of object defined for a key.  This override is done via a custom factory.

Library xml:

```
<!-- DEFAULT MENU -->
<component class="my_menu" key="menu_default"/>
```

App 1 xml:

```
<!-- APP 1 MENU -->
<component class="my_app1_menu" key="menu"/>
```

App 2 xml:

```
<!-- APP 2 MENU -->
<!-- None - use default -->
```

My custom factory then takes in a key value, tries to access Typhoon for "key".  If this is 'nil', then tries again to access: "key" + "_default".

My factory method:

```
- (id) componentForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    TyphoonComponentFactory *factory = [TyphoonComponentFactory defaultFactory];
    @try {
        id obj = [factory componentForKey:key];
        if (obj) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        DLog(@"Couldn't find %@", key);
        DLog(@"Nope");
    }
    // Try Default
    @try {
        key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_default", key];
        id obj = [factory componentForKey:key];
        if (obj) {
            return obj;
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        DLog(@"Couldn't find %@", key);
        DLog(@"No Default");
        DLog(@"Exception: %@", exception);
    }

    return nil;
}
```

As XML implementation of Typhoon is discontinued with the 2.x release.  I would like to move beyond 1.x and our current XML files.  However, I am having a difficult time finding an implementation that would work.

The reason this is important is that each App is essentially a customized skin over a fundamental app defined by the library behavior.  As new features get added, the library's typhoon xml gets populated with "_default" definitions.  Then as we boot up each app with the latest version of the library, at least we have a base implementation defined, so we don't have to track down 'nil' values everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately XML is not supported from Typhoon 2.x onward. However what you wish to achieve is very well supported by the 'assembly' style of configuration'. In summary:

- Definitions can be modularized and organized into multiple assembly files. These files may [refer to each other](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Modularizing-Assemblies).
- On start-up its possible to swap in one assembly in place of another. This can be a sub-class of an assembly, or if assemblies are backed by a protocol, another implementation of that protocol. (In fact as long as the assembly responds to the same messages, that is, provides the named definitions, then Typhoon doesn't care).

**Example:**

Let's say you have the following top-level assembly:

```
@interface MyAppAssembly : TyphoonAssembly

@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) LibraryAssembly *library;

@end
```

You may activate this as follows:

```
MyAppAssembly *assembly = [[MyAppAssembly new] 
    activateWithCollaboratingAssemblies:[CustomizedLibraryAssembly new]];
```

On startup Typhoon will say:

```
CustomizedLibraryAssembly will act in place of LibraryAssembly
```

In `CustomizedLibraryAssembly` you can override any definitions that you like.

Thanks for being a Typhoon early adopter. If you need help porting to a recent version send as an email and we'd be glad to help.

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify between the three mentioned assemblies: LibraryAssembly, CustomizedLibraryAssembly, and MyAppAssembly.  Thank you.

Comment: I've already done that here, actually: https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Modularizing-Assemblies

Comment: Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 0):

so I was able to come up with a solution and we're almost completely moved over, using Typhoon 3.x.

```
@interface LibAssembly : TyphoonAssembly
@end

@implementation LibAssembly

- (id) menu {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[MyMenu class]];
}

@end
```

Then for each app:

```
@interface AppAssembly : LibAssembly
@end

@implementation AppAssembly

- (id) menu {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[AppMenu class]];
}

@end
```

And my factory method changed to:

```
- (id) componentForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    // Check Init
    if (!self.assembly) {
        @throw @"Assembly not initialized properly - please call 'initWithAssemblerClass:' first";
    }

    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(key);
    if ([self.assembly respondsToSelector:selector]) {
        return [self.assembly performSelector:selector];
    }
    return nil;
}

+ (void) initWithAssemblerClass:(Class)assemblerClass
{
    TyphoonAssembly *assembly = [assemblerClass new];
    [assembly activate];
    [MyFactory setAssembly: assembly];
}
```

We then simply had to add to our delegate of each app an initialization step:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // INIT TYPHOON
    [MyFactory initWithAssemblerClass:[AppAssembly class]];
...
}
```